# Service worker SW-Toolbox cached api response gets deleted when navigated to other URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, service-worker

I am using sw-precache module with sw-toolbox. When i navigate to the web app url, the api response is cached in the toolbox cache storage and then if i turn off the internet and refresh the url. Service worker loads the api with a 200OK response from Service Worker Cache but if i navigate to some other url and then come back to the main web app. All the dynamic cached api response of the toolbox cache storage gets deleted. I am using gulp to create the service worker file. The gulp code to generate the file is mentioned below:

```
gulp.task('generate-service-worker', function(callback) {
    var path = require('path');
    var swPrecache = require('sw-precache');
    var rootDir = './src';
    swPrecache.write(path.join(rootDir, 'sw.js'), {
        staticFileGlobs: [rootDir + '/**/*.{js,html,css,png,jpg,gif}'],
        stripPrefix: rootDir,
        importScripts: [
            'sw-toolbox.js',
            'toolbox-routes.js'
        ]
    }, callback);
});
```

The sw-toolbox.js has the code generated from bower components of sw-toolbox library. The toolbox-routes.js has four calls as mentioned below:

```
toolbox.router.get(/^https:\/\/.*\/city/, toolbox.cacheFirst, {});
toolbox.router.get(/^https:\/\/.*\/splash/, toolbox.cacheFirst, {});
toolbox.router.get(/^https:\/\/.*amazonaws\.com\/.*/, toolbox.cacheFirst, {});
toolbox.router.get(/^https:\/\/.*\/api\/booking/, toolbox.networkFirst, {});
```

The city api looks something like this api for which i get a 404 error.

```
https://www.abcd.com/city?includes=venue,car
```

I also get a warning message in the console which says "The FetchEvent for "https://www.abcd.com/city?includes=venue,car" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected."
The service worker file is this

```
'use strict';


importScripts("sw-toolbox.js", "toolbox-routes.js");


/* eslint-disable quotes, comma-spacing */
var PrecacheConfig = [
    ["/app/directives/datepicker/datepicker.html", "fa21126be162d099882132226c9681d2"],
    ["/app/directives/datepicker/datepicker.js", "5ec9f32a36e10feeb03c40d984e74058"],
    ["/app/directives/map/map.js", "cfabf0230663391d8c78f46a2b198f89"],
    ["/index.html", "98b8890a31f58d2362953593bbda427f"],
    ["/index.notification.js", "0cf8aa857d28c309f7b37b97141c1853"],
    ["/sw-toolbox.js", "66531e5962e4dccb0526a2b4cd6364a4"],
    ["/toolbox-routes.js", "e7e168157a8afc939ecfb44da773270d"]
];
/* eslint-enable quotes, comma-spacing */
var CacheNamePrefix = 'sw-precache-v1--' + (self.registration ? self.registration.scope : '') + '-';


var IgnoreUrlParametersMatching = [/^utm_/];



var addDirectoryIndex = function(originalUrl, index) {
    var url = new URL(originalUrl);
    if (url.pathname.slice(-1) === '/') {
        url.pathname += index;
    }
    return url.toString();
};

var getCacheBustedUrl = function(url, param) {
    param = param || Date.now();

    var urlWithCacheBusting = new URL(url);
    urlWithCacheBusting.search += (urlWithCacheBusting.search ? '&' : '') +
        'sw-precache=' + param;

    return urlWithCacheBusting.toString();
};

var isPathWhitelisted = function(whitelist, absoluteUrlString) {
    // If the whitelist is empty, then consider all URLs to be whitelisted.
    if (whitelist.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }

    // Otherwise compare each path regex to the path of the URL passed in.
    var path = (new URL(absoluteUrlString)).pathname;
    return whitelist.some(function(whitelistedPathRegex) {
        return path.match(whitelistedPathRegex);
    });
};

var populateCurrentCacheNames = function(precacheConfig,
    cacheNamePrefix, baseUrl) {
    var absoluteUrlToCacheName = {};
    var currentCacheNamesToAbsoluteUrl = {};

    precacheConfig.forEach(function(cacheOption) {
        var absoluteUrl = new URL(cacheOption[0], baseUrl).toString();
        var cacheName = cacheNamePrefix + absoluteUrl + '-' + cacheOption[1];
        currentCacheNamesToAbsoluteUrl[cacheName] = absoluteUrl;
        absoluteUrlToCacheName[absoluteUrl] = cacheName;
    });

    return {
        absoluteUrlToCacheName: absoluteUrlToCacheName,
        currentCacheNamesToAbsoluteUrl: currentCacheNamesToAbsoluteUrl
    };
};

var stripIgnoredUrlParameters = function(originalUrl,
    ignoreUrlParametersMatching) {
    var url = new URL(originalUrl);

    url.search = url.search.slice(1) // Exclude initial '?'
        .split('&') // Split into an array of 'key=value' strings
        .map(function(kv) {
            return kv.split('='); // Split each 'key=value' string into a [key, value] array
        })
        .filter(function(kv) {
            return ignoreUrlParametersMatching.every(function(ignoredRegex) {
                return !ignoredRegex.test(kv[0]); // Return true iff the key doesn't match any of the regexes.
            });
        })
        .map(function(kv) {
            return kv.join('='); // Join each [key, value] array into a 'key=value' string
        })
        .join('&'); // Join the array of 'key=value' strings into a string with '&' in between each

    return url.toString();
};


var mappings = populateCurrentCacheNames(PrecacheConfig, CacheNamePrefix, self.location);
var AbsoluteUrlToCacheName = mappings.absoluteUrlToCacheName;
var CurrentCacheNamesToAbsoluteUrl = mappings.currentCacheNamesToAbsoluteUrl;

function deleteAllCaches() {
    return caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
        return Promise.all(
            cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
                return caches.delete(cacheName);
            })
        );
    });
}

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        // Take a look at each of the cache names we expect for this version.
        Promise.all(Object.keys(CurrentCacheNamesToAbsoluteUrl).map(function(cacheName) {
            return caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
                // Get a list of all the entries in the specific named cache.
                // For caches that are already populated for a given version of a
                // resource, there should be 1 entry.
                return cache.keys().then(function(keys) {
                    // If there are 0 entries, either because this is a brand new version
                    // of a resource or because the install step was interrupted the
                    // last time it ran, then we need to populate the cache.
                    if (keys.length === 0) {
                        // Use the last bit of the cache name, which contains the hash,
                        // as the cache-busting parameter.
                        // See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/issues/100
                        var cacheBustParam = cacheName.split('-').pop();
                        var urlWithCacheBusting = getCacheBustedUrl(
                            CurrentCacheNamesToAbsoluteUrl[cacheName], cacheBustParam);

                        var request = new Request(urlWithCacheBusting, {
                            credentials: 'same-origin'
                        });
                        return fetch(request).then(function(response) {
                            if (response.ok) {
                                return cache.put(CurrentCacheNamesToAbsoluteUrl[cacheName],
                                    response);
                            }

                            console.error('Request for %s returned a response status %d, ' +
                                'so not attempting to cache it.',
                                urlWithCacheBusting, response.status);
                            // Get rid of the empty cache if we can't add a successful response to it.
                            return caches.delete(cacheName);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        })).then(function() {
            return caches.keys().then(function(allCacheNames) {
                return Promise.all(allCacheNames.filter(function(cacheName) {
                    return cacheName.indexOf(CacheNamePrefix) === 0 &&
                        !(cacheName in CurrentCacheNamesToAbsoluteUrl);
                }).map(function(cacheName) {
                    return caches.delete(cacheName);
                }));
            });
        }).then(function() {
            if (typeof self.skipWaiting === 'function') {
                // Force the SW to transition from installing -> active state
                self.skipWaiting();
            }
        })
    );
});

if (self.clients && (typeof self.clients.claim === 'function')) {
    self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
        event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
    });
}

self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    if (event.data.command === 'delete_all') {
        console.log('About to delete all caches...');
        deleteAllCaches().then(function() {
            console.log('Caches deleted.');
            event.ports[0].postMessage({
                error: null
            });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Caches not deleted:', error);
            event.ports[0].postMessage({
                error: error
            });
        });
    }
});


self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    if (event.request.method === 'GET') {
        var urlWithoutIgnoredParameters = stripIgnoredUrlParameters(event.request.url,
            IgnoreUrlParametersMatching);

        var cacheName = AbsoluteUrlToCacheName[urlWithoutIgnoredParameters];
        var directoryIndex = 'index.html';
        if (!cacheName && directoryIndex) {
            urlWithoutIgnoredParameters = addDirectoryIndex(urlWithoutIgnoredParameters, directoryIndex);
            cacheName = AbsoluteUrlToCacheName[urlWithoutIgnoredParameters];
        }

        var navigateFallback = '';
        // Ideally, this would check for event.request.mode === 'navigate', but that is not widely
        // supported yet:
        // https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=540967
        // https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209081
        if (!cacheName && navigateFallback && event.request.headers.has('accept') &&
            event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html') &&
            /* eslint-disable quotes, comma-spacing */
            isPathWhitelisted([], event.request.url)) {
            /* eslint-enable quotes, comma-spacing */
            var navigateFallbackUrl = new URL(navigateFallback, self.location);
            cacheName = AbsoluteUrlToCacheName[navigateFallbackUrl.toString()];
        }

        if (cacheName) {
            event.respondWith(
                // Rely on the fact that each cache we manage should only have one entry, and return that.
                caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
                    return cache.keys().then(function(keys) {
                        return cache.match(keys[0]).then(function(response) {
                            if (response) {
                                return response;
                            }
                            // If for some reason the response was deleted from the cache,
                            // raise and exception and fall back to the fetch() triggered in the catch().
                            throw Error('The cache ' + cacheName + ' is empty.');
                        });
                    });
                }).catch(function(e) {
                    console.warn('Couldn\'t serve response for "%s" from cache: %O', event.request.url, e);
                    return fetch(event.request);
                })
            );
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks a tonnn in Advance!!!.

Comment: Are you using something like AngularJS with routes (eg.to `/city`)?  If so I'm facing a similar problem.  I don't use `sw-precache` and I haven't worked out the solution though the problem appears to be that routes are internal and can't be handled in the same way - fetching and replaying.

Comment: Actually it seems my problem is more with AWS CloudFront.  The same logic applies in that the url is a route, internal to the Angular application.  And I've removed ServiceWorker as having any involvement in the problem at all.